# Adding up/down vote animation to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, design

**It would be a cool feature to add an up/down vote animation to Stack Overflow!**

A designer made a really cool animation and published it [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/2433937-Up-Down-Vote) on dribble.

It's a nice feature and would make Stack Overflow extraordinary. Stack Overflow is a community for programmers, but why shouldn't we also implement design modules?

[image: animation]

Comment: Why? What purpose does that animation serve? What's the point of adding it? As good or bad as the suggestion may be, you'll need to come up with some kind of reason SO _should_ implement it, other than "It looks cool". Convince "us".

Comment: I would, but I can't. My english isn't good enough.

Comment: How does it _"make stackoverflow extraordinary"_?

Comment: *would make stackoverflow extraordinary* - [android.se] already have [something similar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FMfIR.gif).

Comment: It'd be a nice thing to have, but I'm sure the Stack Exchange developers have more pressing issues...

Comment: To me, it looks tacky. I don't see any value in this.

Comment: Since you can only vote once per post, I don't see the value in it.  Unless you are trying to further encourage any kind of voting... but we don't need  more dubious upvotes.

Comment: @cybermonkey why would it be nice to have?

Comment: @BillWoodger It'd make the site more dynamic, and I quite like the movement of the proposed voting buttons. Much better than the animated buttons provided in the Stack Apps userscripts.

Comment: @cybermonkey thanks. Interesting point. Any thoughts on how often anyone would actually see it, unless staring at something for the Hot Network Questions? I thought votes were already updated in "realtime". Do you think drawing attention to that would encourage further voting?

Comment: Animations are useless time-sinks. Good software helps you accomplish a task without getting in your way. Flashy (useless) animation only serves to make the software itself the focus, not the task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: StackOverflow already eats about 90% of my working day - and now you want to make it even more appealing!?

Comment: If is it something you can't live without, implement it yourself using Stylish or a UserScript.

Comment: That bounce would get reeeeeaallly annoying after about 1 vote.

Answer (score 7):

At best this would have little to no effect and cost developer time for no discernible gain.

At worst it may cause issues due to the implementation, or annoy people.

In any case, not worth it.